# Scala Upserts using jdbc preparedstatement and foreachPartition

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am new to scala/java programming

I need to create a scala jdbcTemplate for mapping multiple columns to a SQL query for a PostgreSQL database.

My insert query has about 80 columns.

something like this:

```
INSERT into schema.table_one (cov_eff_dt,cov_canc_dt,cov_pd_thru_dt,ebill_dt,retro_elig_recv_dt,retro_orig_cov_eff_dt,retro_orig_cov_canc_dt,cobra_eff_dt,elig_grc_prd_thru_dt,lst_prem_pd_dt,pol_ren_dt,partn_nbr,xref_id_partn_nbr,cnsm_id,prfl_id,src_cdb_xref_id,cos_pnl_nbr,src_tmstmp,row_tmstmp,created_dttm,updt_dttm,src_cd,lgcy_pol_nbr,lgcy_src_id,cov_typ_cd,cos_div_cd,mkt_typ_cd,cos_grp_nbr,lgcy_prdt_typ_cd,lgcy_prdt_cd,cov_lvl_typ_cd,shr_arng_cd,shr_arng_oblig_cd,lgcy_pln_var_cd,lgcy_rpt_cd,prdt_srvc_typ_cd,ee_sts_typ_cd,govt_pgm_typ_cd,clm_sys_typ_cd,elig_sys_typ_cd,ces_grp_nbr,mkt_site_cd,row_sts_cd,medica_trvlben_ind,row_user_id,sec_typ_cd,cancel_rsn_typ_cd,cov_pd_thru_rsn_cd,list_bill_typ_cd,billing_sufx_cd,billing_subgrp_nbr,retro_days,retro_typ_cd,retro_ovrd_typ_cd,tops_cov_lvl_typ_cd,lgcy_ben_pln_id,lgcy_prdt_id,rr_ben_grp_nbr,rr_ben_grp_cho_cd,rr_br_cd,rr_un_cd,rr_optout_plan_ind,updt_typ_cd,racf_id,prr_cov_mo,fund_typ_cd,state_of_issue_cd,cobra_mo,cobra_qual_evnt_cd,grndfathered_pol_ind,deriv_cov_ind,cnsm_lgl_enty_nm,indv_grp_typ_cd,src_cov_mnt_typ_cd,pbp_cd,h_cntrct_id,risk_typ_cd,bil_typ_cd,rate_cov_typ_cd,plan_cd,seg_id,src_sys_id) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON CONFLICT (cov_eff_dt,xref_id_partn_nbr,src_cdb_xref_id,src_cd,lgcy_pol_nbr,lgcy_src_id,cov_typ_cd) 
DO  UPDATE SET cov_canc_dt= ?,cov_pd_thru_dt= ?,ebill_dt= ?,retro_elig_recv_dt= ?,retro_orig_cov_eff_dt= ?,retro_orig_cov_canc_dt= ?,cobra_eff_dt= ?,elig_grc_prd_thru_dt= ?,lst_prem_pd_dt= ?,pol_ren_dt= ?,partn_nbr= ?,prfl_id= ?,cnsm_id= ?,cos_pnl_nbr= ?,src_tmstmp= ?,row_tmstmp= ?,updt_dttm= ?,cos_div_cd= ?,mkt_typ_cd= ?,cos_grp_nbr= ?,lgcy_prdt_typ_cd= ?,lgcy_prdt_cd= ?,cov_lvl_typ_cd= ?,shr_arng_cd= ?,shr_arng_oblig_cd= ?,lgcy_pln_var_cd= ?,lgcy_rpt_cd= ?,prdt_srvc_typ_cd= ?,ee_sts_typ_cd= ?,govt_pgm_typ_cd= ?,clm_sys_typ_cd= ?,elig_sys_typ_cd= ?,ces_grp_nbr= ?,mkt_site_cd= ?,row_sts_cd= ?,medica_trvlben_ind= ?,row_user_id= ?,sec_typ_cd= ?,cancel_rsn_typ_cd= ?,cov_pd_thru_rsn_cd= ?,list_bill_typ_cd= ?,billing_sufx_cd= ?,billing_subgrp_nbr= ?,retro_days= ?,retro_typ_cd= ?,retro_ovrd_typ_cd= ?,tops_cov_lvl_typ_cd= ?,lgcy_ben_pln_id= ?,lgcy_prdt_id= ?,rr_ben_grp_nbr= ?,rr_ben_grp_cho_cd= ?,rr_br_cd= ?,rr_un_cd= ?,rr_optout_plan_ind= ?,updt_typ_cd= ?,racf_id= ?,prr_cov_mo= ?,fund_typ_cd= ?,state_of_issue_cd= ?,cobra_mo= ?,cobra_qual_evnt_cd= ?,grndfathered_pol_ind= ?,deriv_cov_ind= ?,cnsm_lgl_enty_nm= ?,indv_grp_typ_cd= ?,src_cov_mnt_typ_cd= ?,pbp_cd= ?,h_cntrct_id= ?,risk_typ_cd= ?,bil_typ_cd= ?,rate_cov_typ_cd= ?,plan_cd= ?,seg_id= ?,src_sys_id= ?
```

The data that needs to be placed in "?" place-holder is stored in another dataframe , named inputdatafiledfwindow .

The mapping for columns, i.e. the functions for setting values in prepared statement is to be generated dynamically.

```
          val inputdatafiledfwindow = inputdatafiledf.select("*").withColumn("rank",row_number().over(windowSpec)).where("rank = 1").drop("rank")

inputdatafiledfwindow.coalesce(10).foreachPartition(partition => {
      val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString, user.toString, password.toString)
      val st = dbc.prepareStatement(updatequeryforInsertAndUpdate)
      partition.grouped(50).foreach(batch => {
        batch.foreach { row => {
                st.setShort(1, row.getShort(0))
                st.setInt(2, row.getInt(1))
                st.setString(3, row.getString(2).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(4, row.getString(3).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(5, row.getString(4).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(6, row.getString(5).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setDate(7, row.getDate(6))
                st.setDate(8, row.getDate(7))
                st.setString(9, row.getString(8).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(10, row.getString(9).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(11, row.getString(10).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(12, row.getString(11).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(13, row.getString(12).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(14, row.getString(13).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(15, row.getString(14).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(16, row.getString(15).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(17, row.getString(16).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(18, row.getString(17).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(19, row.getString(18).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(20, row.getString(19).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(21, row.getString(20).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(22, row.getString(21).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(23, row.getString(22).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(24, row.getString(23).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(25, row.getString(24).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
                st.setString(26, row.getString(25).replaceAll("\\000", ""))
          }

          st.addBatch()
        }
        }
        st.executeBatch()
      })
      dbc.close()
    })
```

Currently I'm trying something like this :

```
val columnNames: scala.Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.columns
    val columnDataTypes: scala.Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.schema.fields.map(x=>x.dataType).map(x=>x.toString)

inputdatafiledfwindow.coalesce(10).foreachPartition(partition  => {
      val columnNames_br = sc.broadcast(inputdatafiledfwindow.columns)
      val columnDataTypes_br = sc.broadcast(inputdatafiledfwindow.schema.fields.map(x=>x.dataType).map(x=>x.toString))
      val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString, user.toString, password.toString)
      val st  = dbc.prepareStatement(updatequeryforInsertAndUpdate)
partition.grouped(50).foreach(batch => {
        batch.foreach { row => {
          for (i<-0 to columnNames.length-1) {
            if (columnDataTypes(i) == "ShortType")
              st.setShort((i+1).toInt, row.getShort(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes(i)== "IntegerType")
              st.setInt((i+1).toInt,row.getInt(i))
            else if (columnDataTypes(i)=="StringType")
              st.setString((i+1).toInt,row.getString(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes(i)=="TimestampType")
              st.setTimestamp((i+1).toInt, row.getTimestamp(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes(i)=="DateType")
              st.setDate((i+1).toInt,row.getDate(i))
            else if (columnDataTypes(i)=="DoubleType")
              st.setDouble((i+1).toInt, row.getDouble(i))
          }
          st.addBatch()
        }
        }
        st.executeBatch()
      })
      dbc.close()
    })
```

And this is giving me :org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable error

Any Ideas or resources I can refer to implement this. 
I know this is possible in java, but I have not worked too much in java, nor in Scala.

Edit : Tried using `braodcast` variable inside foreachPartition
Still getting `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Below is the full exception stack :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2343)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:957)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:956)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:956)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2735)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2735)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2735)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3349)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3345)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2734)
  ... 80 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection, value: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@71c7a55b)
        - field (class: $iw, name: dbc, type: interface java.sql.Connection)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@22459ca5)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@788dd40c)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@31c725ed)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4a367987)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@7cffd7ab)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@3c615880)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@289fa6c2)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@2a5a0934)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@4a04a12a)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@c5fe90a)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@58b67f02)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@243a4a22)
        - field (class: $line77.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $line77.$read, $line77.$read@5f473976)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $line77$read, type: class $line77.$read)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@70fc6803)
        - field (class: $iw, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $iw, $iw@26818b0)
        - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
        - object (class $anonfun$1, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
  ... 98 more
```

Update 2 : Made modifications as suggested by @RamGhadiyaram , but now faced with new NullPointerException. I do not understand where I'm going wrong . 
Surely this must be a simple solution to this .

Below is updated code :

```
val inputdatafiledfwindow = inputdatafiledf.select("*").withColumn("rank",row_number().over(windowSpec)).where("rank = 1").drop("rank")

    val updatequeryforInsertAndUpdate = "INSERT INTO " + schema + table_name + updatequery + " where " + schema + table_name + s".row_tmstmp < '2020-02-17 00:00:00' OR ${table_name}.row_tmstmp < ?"

    val columnNames: scala.Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.columns
    val columnDataTypes: scala.Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.schema.fields.map(x=>x.dataType).map(x=>x.toString)


    inputdatafiledfwindow.foreachPartition(partition  => {
      val columnNames_br = sc.broadcast(columnNames)
      val columnDataTypes_br = sc.broadcast(columnDataTypes)

      val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionString)
      val st  = dbc.prepareStatement(updatequeryforInsertAndUpdate)
      partition.grouped(50).foreach(batch => {
        batch.foreach { row => {
          for (i<-0 to columnNames_br.value.length-1) {
            if (columnDataTypes_br.value(i) == "ShortType")
              st.setShort((i+1), row.getShort(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes_br.value(i)== "IntegerType")
              st.setInt((i+1),row.getInt(i))
            else if (columnDataTypes_br.value(i)=="StringType")
              st.setString((i+1),row.getString(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes_br.value(i)=="TimestampType")
              st.setTimestamp((i+1), row.getTimestamp(i))
            else if(columnDataTypes_br.value(i)=="DateType")
              st.setDate((i+1),row.getDate(i))
            else if (columnDataTypes_br.value(i)=="DoubleType")
              st.setDouble((i+1), row.getDouble(i))
          }
          st.addBatch()
        }
        }
        st.executeBatch()
      })
      dbc.close()
    })
```

and below is the new exception stack :

```
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 176, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 4): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line89.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:87)
        at $line89.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:86)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20/03/25 11:12:49 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.2 in stage 19.0 (TID 210, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 5): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 204, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 2): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.1 in stage 19.0 (TID 201, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 4): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.2 in stage 19.0 (TID 205, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 2): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.2 in stage 19.0 (TID 206, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 2): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.2 in stage 19.0 (TID 207, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 5): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.2 in stage 19.0 (TID 209, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 5): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 208, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 4): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
20/03/25 11:12:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 202, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 4): TaskKilled (stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 203, dbslp1102.uhc.com, executor 5): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:87)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:86)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:924)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2341)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2341)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2341)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2828)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2340)
  ... 86 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:87)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:86)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2069)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: you don't need to repeat the parameter values in the `on conflict do update` part. You can replace them with a referenced to the `excluded` record, e.g. `DO  UPDATE SET cov_canc_dt = excluded.cov_canc_dt, cov_pd_thru_dt = excluded.cov_pd_thru_dt, ...` But apart from that I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,I need to replace the "?" , placeholders with the parameter index and the values from another dataframe

Comment: question is not clear add code snippet you tried and sample dataframe in your post. also visit https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala-jdbc-sql-select-insert-statement-resultset-preparedstatement-example/

Comment: if you are using dataframe api why you need to use spring jdbc template api at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you need to generate all the columns dynamically and insert in to the corresponding data column with correct data type.

for that for the existing dataframe

```
    val columnNames : Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.columns

    val columnDataTypes : Array[String] = inputdatafiledfwindow.schema.fields
                            .map(x=>x.dataType)
                            .map(x=>x.toString)
```

Now you got the columns and corresponding datatypes.

you implement in your loop by checking datatypes dynamically and call appropriate `psmt.setxxx` method for preparedstatement. and array index is parameter index for setXXX .

In this case spring jdbc template is not required the same can be achieved using jdbc as well.

**UPDATE1 :**

---

> Your column types i.e `columnDataTypes` and columns names array i.e. `columnNames` should be broadcasted using
>   broadcast variable to use them in side the foreachpartition that might be
>   root cause of the error ..  `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable error`

---

UPDATE 2 : 
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection
some where your connection has this problem

AFAIK, user and password you are converting as string that might be from different object... but normally it looks okay with your code. re-check that.

***As per Spark docs you can declare url along with user and password like this as well. try it.***

> [JDBC To Other Databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) - The JDBC URL to connect to. The
>   source-specific connection properties may be specified in the URL.
>   e.g., `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret`

UPDATE 3 : Reason for null pointer exception is straight forward.
if you are operating on null then it will lead to null pointer exception

For example: 
`row.getString(8).replaceAll("\\000", "")`
if `row.getString(8)` is null and you are applying `replaceAll` then 
this is null pointer exception. you have to check whether `row.getString(8)` is not null and then you have to apply the function `replaceAll`..

Best way to avoid null pointers are using scala Option.

Another observation is  use scala for each loop rather than java traditional loop.

NOTE : PLEASE ASK SEPARATE QUESTION FOR EACH REQUIREMENT. DON'T MIX INCREMENTALLY. IT WILL CONFUSE OTHERS.

Comment: This is the part which I already have done , but I'm unable to provide the parameter index in setData_type methods using variable , that is what I'd like achieve

Comment: in this `val columnNames : Array[String] ` array index is your parameter index as well

Comment: array index start with 0 some where you are settig wrong values

Comment: i think pstmt index start with 1 just check that

Comment: I've updated the question with what you've told , and get serialization exception

Comment: this is because you cant use columnnames and types as it is you have to broadcast the 2 arrays and within foreachpartition you have to take the values since this is distributed programming

Comment: please ask seperate question for each requirements. its diluting the answer given and will confuse all other viewers

Comment: I tried broadcasting the columnnames and types and used the values inside foreachPartition  , but still I get the serialization exception , any other suggestions

Comment: your serialization error will give serialization debug complete stack along with error you have to see that and post here. if not column names and column types... something you have declared out side foreachpartition and you are trying to use inside for each partition thats the cause of this error .

Comment: i cant see anything other than columnname and columndatatypes

Comment: Have updated the latest code , still the exception exists

Comment: problem in connection creation ... what is user.toString and pwd.toString ? I think you can declarte that inside to see something wrong

Comment: i think user.toString an password.toString has some prob. could you check that. normal way it should work. have researched on many examples. also declared your class as object.

Comment: I made the suggested modification , but now faced with Nullpointer exceptions , in the dataframe some string columns may have empty or null values , but these columns are non-primary key columns  , how I might solve this .

Comment: @Siddharth pls try to understand your 2 problems solved. and you are facing new data issue. you have to ask different question.  This is not the way SO works. pls accept the solution as owner. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/326245